# How to do zooming and paging in UIScrollView with big image size(1.5)MB and 100 images?

Tags: ios4

I am making an application using UIScrollView.In this we have to do zooming and paging of images.I have about 100 images and size of each image is 1.5 MB.Currently i am using scrollview for this ,but when i load more than 10 images the app crashes giving memory warnings.
Please somebody help me as i am stuck with this crashing of app.I have tried many other things also but it does not work.My app is just like photo library of iphone.Plese somebody suggest me what i have to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to debug your code and find where the app is crashing. So you can get the reason of crash.
xCode debuging is very strong and helpful.

put your crashing code here. so someone may tell you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are trying to load too much data into RAM. Are you aware of how little RAM your app has available on the iPhone, and how big an image gets once it is rendered? You should probably try and load images on demand, not pre-load them. Also release them once you're done with them, and release as many cached objects as you can when your app receives a memory warning.

But until you post more information, this is all just poking around in the dark.

Comment: Thanks fzwo... I also think that it is a memory issue...Can u please tell me how to remove images from cache... How can i remove cached objects?...and if i can know what is residing in cache?                 Thanks in advance..

Comment: Vicky, memory management is too big a topic to just answer it here on a few short sentences. I suggest getting a good beginner's book, such as iPhone Programming - the Big Nerd Ranch Guide, and reading the chapters about memory management.